# javax.validation Compatibility issue with WAS 8.5 server

Tags: maven-2, websphere, wsgen

I am trying to deploy my application in WAS 8.5 server, but I see something very weired happending.
When I use the below jar while building , the application builds along with my wsdl without any issue. But it fails during deployment in WAS 8.5 server.
WAS 8.5.5.3 is using jdk 1.6.0.

Dependency used:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
```

My investigation conclude that the wsdl generated from the Endpoint Service during maven build needs the validation api but have to keep the scope as provided, as this jars are
provided by WAS server at runtime.

The above configuration gives the below error.

```
[7/24/16 10:10:25:501 IST] 00000063 WASWSDLGenera E   WSWS7054E: The Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file could not be generated for the com.hex.rbm.erds.ws.endpoint.impl.EntitySearchServiceEndpoint Web service implementation class because of the following error: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
 [7/24/16 10:10:25:507 IST] 00000063 WSModuleDescr E   WSWS7027E: JAX-WS Service Descriptions could not be correctly built because of the following error: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: WSWS7054E: The Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file could not be generated for the com.hex.rbm.erds.ws.endpoint.impl.EntitySearchServiceEndpoint Web service implementation class because of the following error: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
     at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.wsdl.WASWSDLGenerator.generateWsdl(WASWSDLGenerator.java:268)
     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.generateWSDL(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:2084)
     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.<init>(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:449)
     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:401)
     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:297)
     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescriptionFromDBCMap(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:277)
     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.createServiceDescriptionFromDBCMap(DescriptionFactory.java:524)
     at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl.buildJAXWSServices(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:1345)
     at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl._containsJAXWSWebServices(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:519)
     at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl.containsJAXWSWebServices(WSModuleDescriptorImpl.java:494)
     at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deploy.WSCacheWriter.writeModuleCache(WSCacheWriter.java:571)
     at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deploy.WSCacheWriter.writeApplicationCache(WSCacheWriter.java:242)
     at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deploy.WSCacheWriter.writeApplicationCache(WSCacheWriter.java:167)
     at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deploy.PersistentStorageInstallSaveTask.performTask(PersistentStorageInstallSaveTask.java:196)
     at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor$ExpandApp.expand(AppBinaryProcessor.java:1711)
     at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor.postProcessSynchronousExt(AppBinaryProcessor.java:751)
     at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.postProcess(BLABinaryProcessor.java:599)
     at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.onChangeCompletion(BLABinaryProcessor.java:476)
     at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BinaryProcessorWrapper.onChangeCompletion(BinaryProcessorWrapper.java:109)
     at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.postNotify(FileRepository.java:1938)
     at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.update(FileRepository.java:1442)
     at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.client.LocalConfigRepositoryClient.update(LocalConfigRepositoryClient.java:189)
     at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.update(WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.java:665)
     at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.update(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1998)
     at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.synch(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1946)
     at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceImpl.synch(WorkSpaceImpl.java:549)
     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.action.SyncWorkSpaceAction.execute(SyncWorkSpaceAction.java:271)
     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:955)
     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:504)
     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:325)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3878)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:461)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:528)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:314)
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException
     at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:665)
     at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:472)
     at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:298)
     at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:234)
     at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:81)
     at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:64)
     at com.ibm.oti.reflect.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:63)
     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations(Class.java:1879)
     at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:1836)
     at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:1816)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassAnnotation(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:106)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassAnnotation(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:57)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:329)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:483)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:319)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1178)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:194)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:111)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:109)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:161)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:154)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:327)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:153)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:94)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:258)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.buildModel(WsgenTool.java:248)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool.run(WsgenTool.java:123)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.util.WSToolsObjectFactoryImpl.wsgen(WSToolsObjectFactoryImpl.java:61)
     at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.spi.WSToolsObjectFactory.wsgen(WSToolsObjectFactory.java:107)
     at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.wsdl.WASWSDLGenerator.wsgen(WASWSDLGenerator.java:610)
     at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.wsdl.WASWSDLGenerator.generateWsdl(WASWSDLGenerator.java:245)
     ... 62 more
```

But when I remove the provided scope , I am able to deploy without error. But we not suppose to use the validation api jar due to the requirement.
     Can anyone help me what can be done to make this work with the scope as provided , I tried to use higher version of this jar but that did'nt help.
     Temporarily I disabled the `com.ibm.ws.beanvalidation` but that is not the correct way.

Hi Scott, 
Tried to generate wsdl using the wsgen where I use:
%Java_Home% as \IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java. But no issue during the build and it geneates without any issue.

```
%Java_Home%\bin\wsgen -d target\classes -cp target\classes;%Nexus_Home%\org\springframework\spring-web\3.0.4.RELEASE\spring-web-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar;%Nexus_Home%\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.0.4.RELEASE\spring-beans-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar;%Nexus_Home%\com\hex\cobam\rds\cobam-rds-services\2.14.0-SNAPSHOT\cobam-rds-services-2.14.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;%Nexus_Home%\com\hex\cobam\core\cobam-core-domain\1.0.64\cobam-core-domain-1.0.64.jar;%Nexus_Home%\com\hex\cobam\rds\cobam-rds-domain\2.4.0-SNAPSHOT\cobam-rds-domain-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;%Nexus_Home%\com\hex\cobam\core\cobam-core-exception\1.0.20\cobam-core-exception-1.0.20.jar;%Nexus_Home%\joda-time\joda-time\2.9.4\joda-time-2.9.4.jar;%Java_Home%\jre\..\lib\tools.jar -wsdl -r  target\classes com.hex.cobam.rds.ws.endpoint.impl.EntitySearchServiceEndpoint
```

The endpoint internally calls this class which uses validation api:

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.xml.ws.WebFault;

@WebFault(faultBean = "com.hex.bam.core.exception.BusinessError", name = "searchRequestValidationException", targetNamespace = RDS_SERVICE_NAMESPACE)
public class SearchRequestValidationException extends BamBusinessException {

    public SearchRequestValidationException(Set<ConstraintViolation<Criteria>> constraintViolations) {
        super(constraintViolations);
}
```

Adding some more details to it:

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;

public abstract class BamBusinessException extends Exception {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected <C> BamBusinessException(Set<ConstraintViolation<C>> constraintViolations) {
        error = ErrorFactory.buildBusinessError(this, constraintViolations);
    }
}


public class ErrorFactory {
public static <T extends BamBusinessException, C> BusinessError buildBusinessError(
            T exception, Set<ConstraintViolation<C>> constraintViolations) {
        BusinessError error = buildBusinessError(exception);

        List<BasicConstraintViolation> violations = new ArrayList<BasicConstraintViolation>();
        if (constraintViolations != null) {
            for (ConstraintViolation<C> violation : constraintViolations) {
                violations.add(parse(violation));
            }
        }

        error.setConstraintViolationList(violations);

        return error;
    }
}


import static com.hex.bam.core.dto.NamespaceConstants.CORE_DTO_NAMESPACE;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlType(namespace = CORE_DTO_NAMESPACE)
public class BasicConstraintViolation {

    private String propertyPath;

    private String resourceKey;

    public void setPropertyPath(String propertyPath) {
        this.propertyPath = propertyPath;
    }

    public void setResourceKey(String resourceKey) {
        this.resourceKey = resourceKey;
    }

    public String getResourceKey() {
        return resourceKey;
    }

    public String getPropertyPath() {
        return propertyPath;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + getPropertyPath() + ":::" + getResourceKey() + "}";
    }

import javax.jws.HandlerChain;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

@HandlerChain(file = "../../../../../../../handler-chain.xml")
@javax.jws.WebService(endpointInterface = ENDPOINT_INTERFACE, targetNamespace = RDS_SERVICE_NAMESPACE, serviceName = SERVICE_NAME, portName = PORT_NAME)
@XmlSeeAlso({ com.hex.bam.rds.domain.Organisation.class, com.hex.bam.rds.domain.Individual.class })
public class EntitySearchServiceEndpoint extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements EntitySearchService {

    @Autowired
    private SearchService searchService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;
    @Autowired
    private ModelSupportService defaultModelSupportService;
    @Autowired
    private RegulatoryClassificationService regulatoryClassificationService;

    @Override
    public IndividualSearchResults findIndividuals(IndividualSearchCriteria individualSearchCriteria,
            ClientIdentification clientIdentification) throws CobamSystemException, SearchRequestValidationException {
        try {
            authenticationService.authenticateOnBehalfOfUser(clientIdentification);
            assertParameterSuppliedThrowsSearchRequestValidationException(individualSearchCriteria);
            defaultModelSupportService.initialiseReferenceDatum(individualSearchCriteria, TreeWalker.MAX_DEPTH);
            return searchService.findIndividuals(individualSearchCriteria);
        } catch (RuntimeException runtimeException) {
            throw ErrorFactory.buildAndLogCobamSystemException(runtimeException);
        }
    }
}

@WebService(name = "EntitySearchService", targetNamespace = RDS_SERVICE_NAMESPACE)
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.BARE)
@XmlSeeAlso({ Individual.class, Organisation.class })
public interface EntitySearchService {

 @WebMethod(operationName = "findOrganisations", action = RDS_SERVICE_NAMESPACE + "findOrganisations")
    @WebResult(name = "organisationSearchResults", targetNamespace = ERDS_SERVICE_NAMESPACE)
    OrganisationSearchResults findOrganisations(
            @WebParam(name = "organisationSearchCriteria") OrganisationSearchCriteria organisationSearchCriteria,
            @WebParam(name = "findOrganisationsClientIdentification", header = true) ClientIdentification clientIdentification)
            throws BamSystemException, SearchRequestValidationException;

}

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import com.hex.bam.core.dto.BasicConstraintViolation;

@XmlType(name = "businessError", namespace = EXCEPTION_NAMESPACE)
public class BusinessError extends Error {

    private final List<BasicConstraintViolation> constraintViolationList;

    public BusinessError(Date occuredAt, String resourceKey, String guid,
            List<BasicConstraintViolation> constraintViolationList) {
        super(occuredAt, resourceKey, guid);
        this.constraintViolationList = constraintViolationList;
    }

    public List<BasicConstraintViolation> getConstraintViolationList() {
        return constraintViolationList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String violations = constraintViolationList != null ? constraintViolationList.toString() : " none ";
        return getGuid() + " - Business Error - " + getResourceKey() + " [" + violations + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you're doing some BeanValidation on one of your JAXB types.   Why don't you just show some snippets of your Java code . Did you try generating the WSDL in RAD or wsgen to see if somehow it's just an issue with the classloader path in the case you leave the WSDL gen until deploy time (not saying if that's likely to make a difference or not)?

Comment: I have provided some details let me know your input.

Comment: I'd need to see more detail to make a guess.  I don't think the exception constructor you showed would even get mapped to WSDL/XSD by wsgen.   But it's hard to tell since you don't show the superclass.     Or, maybe just generate pre-deployment since you have found that that works.

Comment: Hi Scott, added some more details , please let me know what could be the issue.

Comment: I don't know whether it's related, but that `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` is a JVM bug.  Upgrade to the latest SDK fixpak, and if the error persists, open a PMR with IBM.

Comment: I tried with JDK 1.7 too and in all version only removing the scope as provided solved it. But my constraint is I can't remove this scope.

Comment: Hm.. ArrayStoreException means you are tying to put something into an array with different type than which it has been defined with. I don't think this is a JVM bug...It looks more like using different implementations based on the same interface (JAXB / RAD ?) Furthermore you need to use the correct versions of Axis which is part of Websphere and the same version in your code otherwise this will cause such things as far as i know...If you remove provided this means you are using the your own packages (defined as dependency) otherwise you are using those which Websphere contains.

Comment: Is there any jar for Axis which I need to look into, do WAS use any jar for this.Any suggestion to fix this issue will be great help.